# How to remove InputAlias created using notations package

Tags: custom-notation, notation

If i create a custom input alias using `Notation` package's `AddInputAlias`. Now it appears in the list generated by `ActiveInputAliases[]` and can be used within the current notebook even if it is closed or kernel restarted. My question is how do i remove this `InputAlias`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the alias is `kk` you can remove it using:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAliases, "kk"}] = Inherited
```

Comment: Thank you it works!